# In numpy, how to multiply a polynomial by an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, polynomials

I am trying to multiply a polynomial by a function represented as a numpy array, so that in the end I can have an object that is a function that can be manipulated as a function (take derivatives, etc.).  So this is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.hermite import Hermite as He

N = 15
L = 2

x = np.zeros(N,dtype=float)
for i in range(N):
    x[i] = (i-N//2)*L/N

h = He([0,1,0])*np.exp(-x*x/2)
print(h(x))
print(2*x*np.exp(-x*x/2))
```

And my result is:

```
[ 2.72028782e+06 -1.36933903e+07 -1.73242347e+07 -1.17112917e+07
 -3.41036609e+06  2.02073199e+06  2.55751492e+06 -1.11607501e-09
 -1.76349396e+06  4.85092636e+05  6.89290562e+06  1.37361270e+07
  1.48504968e+07  5.00284621e+06 -1.60432564e+07]
[-1.20755633 -1.16183846 -1.06764987 -0.92525704 -0.73849308 -0.51470353
 -0.2643068   0.          0.2643068   0.51470353  0.73849308  0.92525704
  1.06764987  1.16183846  1.20755633]
```

Since H_1(x) = 2x, I was expecting the two results to be the same, but they are not.  How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at your code and understood that you wish to multiply the Hermite polynomial by the array. The error consists in the fact that you need to multiply the exponential ***after*** you defined the polynomial:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.hermite import 
Hermite as He

N = 15
L = 2

x = np.zeros(N,dtype=float)
for i in range(N):
   x[i] = (i-N//2)*L/N

h = He([0,1,0])

print(h(x)*np.exp(-x*x/2))

print(2*x*np.exp(-x*x/2))
```

Which would result in:

```
[-1.20755633 -1.16183846 -1.06764987 
-0.92525704 -0.73849308 -0.51470353
-0.2643068   0.          0.2643068   
0.51470353  0.73849308  0.92525704
1.06764987  1.16183846  1.20755633]

[-1.20755633 -1.16183846 -1.06764987 
-0.92525704 -0.73849308 -0.51470353
-0.2643068   0.          0.2643068   
0.51470353  0.73849308  0.92525704
1.06764987  1.16183846  1.20755633]
```

If you still want to keep a reusable function, I would recommend:

```
def h(i):
    a = He([0,1,0])
    z = a(i)*(np.exp(-i*i/2))
    return z

print(h(x))
print(2*x*np.exp(-x*x/2))
```

I'm not 100% sure why this happens, but what I did understand is that when defining the Hermite, the term `np.exp(-x*x/2)` is taken into consideration:

[Default Hermite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCtuy.png)

[Multiplied Hermite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn4Dr.png)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Well I was hoping to have an object that I could do function operations on like derivatives.  I don't think this solution would enable me to do that, would it?